# Integrating windows desktop notifications with python unittests

Tags: python, unit-testing, winapi, notifications, balloon-tip

I am try to write a script that tests whether a site is up and sends a desktop notification if it is not. I plan to automate a batch file so that it is run every hour.
Currently, I have two scripts, one that tests whether the site is up, and one that sends a desktop notification. however, I am having trouble integrating them.
My test script looks like:

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import os
import time
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from urllib.request import urlopen
from html.parser import HTMLParser
import notification_script


gecko = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'geckodriver'))
binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, executable_path=gecko+'.exe')


class PythonOrgSearch(unittest.TestCase):

#sets up driver to run tests
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = driver

    def test_server(self):
        driver=self.driver
        driver.get("http://website.com")
        if self.assertIn("stuff", driver.title):
            print(")
        else:
            print("site not up")
        driver.close()
```

if **name** == "**main**":
    unittest.main()

My notification script looks like:

```
from win32api import *
from win32gui import *
import win32con
import sys, os
import struct
import time

class WindowsBalloonTip:
    def __init__(self, title, msg):
        message_map = {
                win32con.WM_DESTROY: self.OnDestroy,
        }
        # Register the Window class.
        wc = WNDCLASS()
        hinst = wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(None)
        wc.lpszClassName = "PythonTaskbar"
        wc.lpfnWndProc = message_map # could also specify a wndproc.
        classAtom = RegisterClass(wc)
        # Create the Window.
        style = win32con.WS_OVERLAPPED | win32con.WS_SYSMENU
        self.hwnd = CreateWindow( classAtom, "Taskbar", style, \
                0, 0, win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT, win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT, \
                0, 0, hinst, None)
        UpdateWindow(self.hwnd)
        iconPathName = os.path.abspath(os.path.join( sys.path[0], "balloontip.ico" ))
        icon_flags = win32con.LR_LOADFROMFILE | win32con.LR_DEFAULTSIZE
        try:
           hicon = LoadImage(hinst, iconPathName, \
                    win32con.IMAGE_ICON, 0, 0, icon_flags)
        except:
          hicon = LoadIcon(0, win32con.IDI_APPLICATION)
        flags = NIF_ICON | NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_TIP
        nid = (self.hwnd, 0, flags, win32con.WM_USER+20, hicon, "tooltip")
        Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, nid)
        Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_MODIFY, \
                         (self.hwnd, 0, NIF_INFO, win32con.WM_USER+20,\
                          hicon, "Balloon  tooltip",msg,200,title))
        # self.show_balloon(title, msg)
        time.sleep(30)
        DestroyWindow(self.hwnd)
    def OnDestroy(self, hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam):
        nid = (self.hwnd, 0)
        Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_DELETE, nid)
        PostQuitMessage(0) # Terminate the app.

def balloon_tip(title, msg):
    w=WindowsBalloonTip(title, msg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    balloon_tip("Server Notification", "Server is down")
```

My issue is that I can't figure how to integrate these into one script, that will send a desktop notification on the status of the site/ whether it is down. If you know how to do so, please let me know, I'm pretty lost on it. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply declare the class and function for WindowsBalloonTips above the first script.

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import os
import time
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from urllib.request import urlopen
from html.parser import HTMLParser
import notification_script
from win32api import *
from win32gui import *
import win32con
import sys
import struct
import time


gecko = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'geckodriver'))
binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, executable_path=gecko+'.exe')

class WindowsBalloonTip:
    def __init__(self, title, msg):
        message_map = {
                win32con.WM_DESTROY: self.OnDestroy,
        }
        # Register the Window class.
        wc = WNDCLASS()
        hinst = wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(None)
        wc.lpszClassName = "PythonTaskbar"
        wc.lpfnWndProc = message_map # could also specify a wndproc.
        classAtom = RegisterClass(wc)
        # Create the Window.
        style = win32con.WS_OVERLAPPED | win32con.WS_SYSMENU
        self.hwnd = CreateWindow( classAtom, "Taskbar", style, \
                0, 0, win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT, win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT, \
                0, 0, hinst, None)
        UpdateWindow(self.hwnd)
        iconPathName = os.path.abspath(os.path.join( sys.path[0], "balloontip.ico" ))
        icon_flags = win32con.LR_LOADFROMFILE | win32con.LR_DEFAULTSIZE
        try:
           hicon = LoadImage(hinst, iconPathName, \
                    win32con.IMAGE_ICON, 0, 0, icon_flags)
        except:
          hicon = LoadIcon(0, win32con.IDI_APPLICATION)
        flags = NIF_ICON | NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_TIP
        nid = (self.hwnd, 0, flags, win32con.WM_USER+20, hicon, "tooltip")
        Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, nid)
        Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_MODIFY, \
                         (self.hwnd, 0, NIF_INFO, win32con.WM_USER+20,\
                          hicon, "Balloon  tooltip",msg,200,title))
        # self.show_balloon(title, msg)
        time.sleep(30)
        DestroyWindow(self.hwnd)
    def OnDestroy(self, hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam):
        nid = (self.hwnd, 0)
        Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_DELETE, nid)
        PostQuitMessage(0) # Terminate the app.

def balloon_tip(title, msg):
    w=WindowsBalloonTip(title, msg)

class PythonOrgSearch(unittest.TestCase):

    #sets up driver to run tests
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = driver

    def test_server(self):
        driver=self.driver
        driver.get("http://website.com")
        if self.assertIn("stuff", driver.title):
            # Optionally notify the user if the site is up
            balloon_tip("Server Notification", "Server is up")
        else:
            balloon_tip("Server Notification", "Server is down")
        driver.close()


# The main function to acutally call the test_server command
def main():

    driver = PythonOrgSearch()
    driver.test_server()

# Call the main function to start the program
main()
```

Then call the balloon_tip function as needed from the main script.

Comment: This seems like it would work except that when I run it the driver/browser opens but nothing else happens. Is there somewhere a function should be being called but is not?

Comment: Well, you need to have a main function that actually runs. This script doesn't include a main function yet, just the class `PythonOrgSearch` and its dependencies. The main function should create an instance of `PythonOrgSearch` and call the `test_server()` function of that instance.

Comment: Can you show a code example. I am not sure qhat you meean by that. I appended this: 
if __name__== '__main__':
 unittest.main()
to the end of the script. Am I missing something?

Comment: formatting in that comment is weird i am unsure why

Comment: I have edited my comment to include a main function. It creates the `PythonOrgSearch` object and calls `test_server()` from it.